# Implement an Own Payment Gateway

Tags: magento-1.7, payment, payment-gateway

I  want to implement a payment gateway (NTPnow) in Magento for credit card processing.

I am providing web-services of Magento for POS app and POS team want to make credit cart payment at end of Magento using this specific payment method

I searched on google for it but not find any solution.

How can implement a new payment method in Magento??

Comment: Please remove your cross-posting from stackoverflow, http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3601/magento-implement-ntpnow-payment-gateway thank you

Answer (score 2):

The only advice I can give is to look at an already functional payment gateway extension - and adjust it to suit your API and needs.

Handling of credit card information is incredibly important; and if this is your first attempt at doing such - you are potentially putting every customer using your extension at risk.

You might also want to look at the EE Payment Bridge if you are looking at storing data at any point.

Answer (score 2):

go through the following links

[Create Payment method](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-payment-method)

[Payment Method - API based](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-payment-method-api-based)

I think this may help you. Cheers!